# Pointers In C and other languages

Tags: pointers

Consider the following simple function in c++...

```
int function(int *a, int x)
{
     return x*x;
}
```

My question is: How to translate the above function into an ada function as I can't write the pointer.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you want to write the equivalent Ada subprogram, or do you want to call the C function from Ada? And what do you want `a` to do (I ask because your example doesn’t actually use it). You might be going to save the pointer for later use, or you might want to update the current value of `*a`; in which case, do you care what the previous value was?

Comment: Please do not change the titles of posts like you did. This is not a forum. With a title like that - how will anyone know what the content of the post really is?

Comment: To mark a post as "solved" as you are implying, all you have to do is mark an answer as accepted. As you can see, a green checkmark appears and *this* is what indicates that a post has been answered.

Comment: @Lix sorry I didnot know

Comment: @user3459170 - no worries! Now you know :) I've taken the liberty of reverting the changes you made to your other questions too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass pointers (access types) into Ada functions or procedures but you normally don't want to.

The usual reason for passing a pointer into a C function is to allow the function to modify the thing pointed at.

C doesn't have any better way of letting you do that; Ada does.

Instead of passing values or pointers (or in C++, references), you pass objects with appropriate modes : In, Out, In Out, describing how the argument is used.

- In : the argument is only an input and can't be modified. (This is the default; without specifying a Mode you get mode In.
- Out : the argument is an output (to a procedure : functions shouldn't have Out parameters, but Ada-2012 relaxes this rule) and the procedure will update the value in the argument.
- In Out : not surprisingly, both an input and an output.

So you probably want to write

```
function My_Func (a : in out Integer;
                  x : in     Integer) return integer is
begin
   return x * x;
end My_Func;
```

but there are several problems:

1. You can't name it "function" because that's a reserved word
2. The unused argument is an error
3. (until Ada-2012) you can't have an `out` or `in out` argument from a function; they are reserved for procedures (which C would call "void functions")

The last one may look odd : Ada's functions are ideally functions in the mathematical sense, not the C sense of being "any old subprogram". That is, they accept arguments, process them *without modifying them or anything else* and return a result. These are called *pure functions* and like [proper operators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14468636/why-are-there-no-augmented-assignment-operators-like-or-in-ada/14469447#14469447) you can optimise around them much more safely than is otherwise true.

Ada unlike some stricter languages, does allow *impure functions* which may modify state (e.g. updating the seed in a random generator on each call) and as of 2012 also allows `out` and `in out` parameters; a legitimate use would be to update an "OK" flag in a series of operations like file reads.

So how do we normally use `Out` parameters? In a procedure, which like a statement, can modify things (assignment) or change state. So if you meant to use the argument `a` you might write:

```
procedure My_Proc (a :    out Integer;
                   x : in     Integer) is
begin
   a := x * x;
end My_Proc;
```

Think of a function as an abstraction over an expression, while a procedure abstracts over a statement. (This leads to some obvious refactorings; replace expression with function, statement or block with procedure).

If this doesn't actually answer the question and you think you might really need pointers, add a comment or update the question.

Comment: Typo: Ada uses `;`, not `,`, to separate parameters in declarations.

Comment: Mr. Brian, I'm just trying to convert a heap sorting algorithm I created in c++ into ada. The problem I faced is that I needed to pass by reference the array created inside the main to other procedures... but I couldn't manage to make those procedures accept a reference to an array as an argument. In c++, even something in the parameters like `int *a` would accept the array. So please tell me how to do this in ada. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: @ajb : thanks for correction; I should have compiled it!

Comment: @user3459170 : just pass the array as mode `in out` as Simon says. No pointers!

Answer (score 1):

Further to Brian’s answer, you might declare

```
type Arr is array (Integer range <>) of Integer;
```

(that’s to say, all instances of `Arr` are arrays containing `Integer`s indexed by `Integer`s, but different instances can have different bounds). There are three common ways of writing subprograms that use `Arr`s.

If you only want to read the values, use (or default to) `in` mode:

```
function Sum (A : Arr) return Integer
is
   Total : Integer := 0;
begin
   for J in A'Range loop
      Total := Total + A (J);
   end loop;
   return Total;
end Sum;
```

If you don’t care what the previous contents were, use `out` mode:

```
procedure Initialize (A : out Arr; To : Integer)
is
begin
   for J in A'Range loop
      A (J) := To;
   end loop;
end Initialize;
```

If you want to update the previous contents, use `in out` mode:

```
procedure Multiply (A : in out Arr; By : Integer)
is
begin
   for J in A'Range loop
      A (J) := A (J) * By;
   end loop;
end Multiply;
```

Sticking to Ada 2005, functions aren’t allowed to have `out` or `in out` parameters, but (as NWS said) you can use `access` mode:

```
function Divide_And_Sum (A : access Arr; By : Integer) return Integer
is
   Sum : Integer := 0;
begin
   for J in A'Range loop
      A (J) := A (J) / By;
      Sum := Sum + A (J);
   end loop;
   return Sum;
end Divide_And_Sum;
```

but then you need to declare the actual array `aliased`:

```
T : aliased Arr := (0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
```

and pass its `’Access` in the call:

```
New_Sum := Divide_And_Sum (T'Access, 2);
```

Answer (score 0):

In Ada, Pointers are not implicitly defined (by using a *), you need to define their types explicitly like below:

```
   type Int_Ptr is access Integer;

   function My_Func (A : in Int_Ptr; 
                     X : in integer) return Integer is 
   begin
      return X*X;
   end My_Func;
```

Then you can produce a function exactly like the C++ one you supplied.
How this helps your problem im not sure. @Brian Drummond has a useful discussion of this in his answer.